# Boost not found?

Tags: boost, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12 to 14.04. I also upgraded ROS Groovy to Indigo.

However, when I migrated one of my packages, it could not find boost anymore during compilation :

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so', needed by ...
```

The compiler does seem to find Boost :

```
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
```

And Boost seems to be properly installed, although without the ***-mt*** part under :

```
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
```

In my CMakeLists I have the following code regarding Boost :

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(my_node ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

The issue look similar to the one posted here : http://answers.ros.org/question/193486/64-bit-catkin-boost-issue/#204049

Thank you for any ideas!

Ruud

PS: My total CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(visual_servo_control)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  tf
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation 
  geometry_msgs
  image_transport
)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
    FILES
)

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
   FILES
   request_servo_velocity_vector.srv
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES hdev_engine
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(my_node src/my_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
add_dependencies(my_node my_node_generate_messages_cpp)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(my_node ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

find_package(VISP REQUIRED)
include_directories(${VISP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(my_node ${VISP_LIBRARIES})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(my_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(cycle_node src/cycle_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cycle_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204290/boost-not-found?/) by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently the library OGRE included in the ViSP library is causing this error. Recompiling ViSP without OGRE solves the problem.

More information can be found here: https://gforge.inria.fr/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33391&forum_id=1295&group_id=397

However a full solution or a deeper understanding what causes this issue is not yet provided.

---

Originally posted by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) with karma: 212 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1